# Melt and Recast into a new dataframe in r

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I just downloaded a lot of temperature data from one of our dataloggers. The dataframe gives me mean hourly observations of temperature for 1691 hours for 87 temperature sensors (so there is a lot of data here). This looks something like this

> ```
> D1_A     D1_B     D1_C
> 13.43    14.39    12.33
> 12.62    13.53    11.56
> 11.67    12.56    10.36
> 10.83    11.62    9.47
> ```

I would like to reshape this dataset into a matrix that looks like this:

```
#create a blank matrix 5 columns 131898 rows 
matrix1<-matrix(nrow=131898, ncol=5)
colnames(matrix1)<- c("year", "ID", "Soil_Layer", "Hour", "Temperature")
```

where:

```
year is always "2012"
ID corresponds to the header ID (e.g. D1)
Soil_Layer corresponds to the second bit of the header (e.g. A, B, or C)
Hour= 1:1691 for each sensor 
and Temperature= the observed values in the original dataframe.
```

Can this be done with the reshape package in r? Does this need to be done as a loop? Any input on how to handle this dataset would be useful. Cheers!

Comment: where does the 131898 come from? 1691*87 = 147117.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want...you can take advantage of the `colsplit()` and `melt()` functions in package `reshape2`. It's not clear where you identify the `Hour` for the data, so I assumed it was ordered from the original dataset. If that's not the case, update your question:

```
library(reshape2)
#read in your data
x <- read.table(text = "

    D1_A    D1_B  D1_C
    13.43 14.39   12.33
    12.62 13.53   11.56
    11.67 12.56   10.36
    10.83 11.62   9.47
    9.98  10.77   9.04
    9.24  10.06   8.65
    8.89  9.55    8.78
    9.01  9.39    9.88
", header = TRUE)

#add hour index, if data isn't ordered, replace this with whatever 
#tells you which hour goes where
x$hour <- 1:nrow(x)
#Melt into long format
x.m <- melt(x, id.vars = "hour")
#Split into two columns
x.m[, c("ID", "Soil_Layer")] <- colsplit(x.m$variable, "_", c("ID", "Soil_Layer"))
#Add the year
x.m$year <- 2012

#Return the first 6 rows
head(x.m[, c("year", "ID", "Soil_Layer", "hour", "value")])
#----
  year ID Soil_Layer hour value
1 2012 D1          A    1 13.43
2 2012 D1          A    2 12.62
3 2012 D1          A    3 11.67
4 2012 D1          A    4 10.83
5 2012 D1          A    5  9.98
6 2012 D1          A    6  9.24
```